# Cast to void* with offset and then back to original type

Tags: c++, arrays, pointer-arithmetic, strict-aliasing, static-cast

Is this code legal? Does it violate strict aliasing? It does compile and work in the expected way.

```
using ARR3 = int [3];
using ARR2 = int [2];
ARR3 arr = {1, 2, 3};
ARR2 & off_by_1 = *static_cast<ARR2*>(static_cast<void*>(&(arr[1])));
std::cout << off_by_1[0] << std::endl;
```

It prints out 2

Comment: What's the motivation for writing such code?

Comment: As long as the initial pointer type is aligned with the final pointer type, it is legal (though definitely not advised)

Comment: @GillBates that's exactly what I wanted to know. So this doesn't violate strict aliasing?

Comment: @RSahu For an aggregate class, to allow offsets within for subclasses. eg getting a slice of an array doing only static_cast.

Comment: IMO the code is correct, however the standard is not precise and people have differing views

Comment: Why do you need a pointer to a(slice of a)n array, as opposed to a pointer to one of the array elements?

Comment: I would say it breaks strict aliasing rules. (even if it should work on most compiler)

Comment: You have an `ARR2&`, but you never initialized an `int[2]` for it to reference. It should work on most compilers, but I think it’s UB and wouldn’t be surprised if something similar (like setting one of the elements through `off_by_one` and reading it through `arr`) failed to work as expected.